# Aceptar solo letras por teclado en una condición if

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con **JavaScript** y no he encontrado un ejemplo que me funcione. Mi problema es que quiero saber como puedo **limitar la entrada exclusiva de letras** por entrada de teclado en un caso oncreto.

Mi práctica es para saber si un **CIF** de empresa es correcto o no. Un CIF esta constituido por 9 dígitos: El primer dígito define el tipo de empresa (letra), el segundo y tercero define la provincio (numero), los siguientes 5 el identificador numérico y el último, y en el que tengo problemas, depende de la letra del primer dígito, que dependiendo su valor solo aceptará letras, numeros o ambos. Coloco el código hasta el momento.

```
//Usaremos la variable cif como base del ejercicio
var cif;

//Pediremos la introducción mediante teclado del cif a buscar.
cif=prompt('Introduce un CIF:','');

if(cif==null){ //Si cuando se nos pide introducir pulsamos Cancelar
    alert("Has presionado Cancelar");
    document.write('Cierra la ventana o recargalá para volver a intentarlo');
 }  
 if(cif.length>9){
    document.write('Un CIF no puede disponer de más de 9 dígitos');
 }
  if(cif.length<9){
    document.write('Un CIF no puede disponer de menos de 9 dígitos');
 }
 if(cif.length==9){
        document.write('correcto1');
    if(cif.charAt(0) =='A' || cif.charAt(0)=='B' || cif.charAt(0)=='C' || cif.charAt(0)=='D' || cif.charAt(0)=='E' || cif.charAt(0)=='F' || cif.charAt(0)=='G' || cif.charAt(0)=='H' || cif.charAt(0)=='K' || cif.charAt(0)=='L' || cif.charAt(0)=='M' || cif.charAt(0)=='N' || cif.charAt(0)=='P' || cif.charAt(0)=='Q' || cif.charAt(0)=='S'){
        document.write('correcto2');
        if(cif.substr(1,3)>=1){
            document.write('correcto3');
            if(cif.substr(3,5)>=0){
                document.write('correcto4');
                if(cif.charAt(0)=='K' || cif.charAt(0)=='P' || cif.charAt(0)=='Q' || cif.charAt(0)=='S'){
                    if(){
                        document.write('correcto5.1');
                    }

                }
                else if(cif.charAt(0)=='A' || cif.charAt(0)=='B' || cif.charAt(0)=='E' || cif.charAt(0)=='H'){
                    if(cif.charAt(8)>=0){
                        document.write('correcto5.2');
                    }
                }
                else{
                    document.write('correcto5.3');
                }
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

El problema lo tengo en el tercer if empezando desde abajo es que no se como poner algo parecido a if(cif.charAt(8)==[A-Z]).

Como veis, en este ejemplo queremos que todos los CIF que empiecen por K, P, Q y S **solo puedan tener como último dígito una letra** y no números.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es una expresión regular con el rango `[A-Z]`, luego llamas al método `test()` de la expresión regular y pasas como parámetro el caracter a evaluar, si hay coincidencia devuelve `true`:

```
    regex = /[A-Z]/;
    if(regex.test(cif.charAt(8))){
    // el caracter en la posicion 8 está entre [A-Z]
    }
```